# How to multiply alternate values using R?

Tags: r

I have a list of dates and corresponding values. I want to segregate only dates with the month September or any alternate date, and multiply the corresponding value by 10. Please guide me on this.

```
    Date    Index values
Jan 2011            2134
Feb 2011            2258
Mar 2011            2032
Aug 2011            2012
Sep 2011            2236
Sep 2012            2235
Sep 2013            2238
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to separate the Dates with 'Sep' and multiply the 'Index_vaues' with 10, create a numeric row index for elements that 'Sep' in 'Date' column using `grep`.  Use that index to subset the 'Index_values' and multiply that elements with '10'.

```
indx <- grep('Sep', df1$Date)
df1$Index_values[indx] <- df1$Index_values[indx]*10
df1[indx,]
#      Date Index_values
#5 Sep 2011        22360
#6 Sep 2012        22350
#7 Sep 2013        22380
```

Or using `data.table`, we could do this more faster.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), get the first three characters of 'Date' with `substr`, create a logical index (`=='Sep'`) and assign (`:=`) the 'Index_values' which are TRUE for the `i` by multiplying with `10`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[substr(Date, 1,3)=='Sep', Index_values:= 10*Index_values]
```

If you need to `subset` the 'Date' with 'Sep'

```
setDT(df1)[substr(Date, 1,3)=='Sep'][, Index_values:=10*Index_values]
```

Comment: I am expecting the output to be like this Sep 2011            22360
7 Sep 2012            22350
8 Sep 2013            22380

Comment: @Niveditajoshi  So you wanted to `subset` the dataset to include only `Sep` rows

Comment: Yes i want to subset dates with september

Comment: Akrun, thanks for answering the question and sharing the data.table/assignment concept.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using time series when you working with time-bound observations. You can do what you need easily with `xts` time series object (suppose `dt` is your `data.frame`):

```
ts=xts(df$Index.values, order.by=as.Date(df$Date,'%b %Y'))
ts$Index.values['2011-01']=ts$Index.values['2011-01']*10
ts['2011-01']
```